# routing from components into main component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have 3 components that is login , signup and dashboard the problem is that they are routed from within i mean that user can route from login component to signup component and vice versa. the exact path is sign up  but if path="/"then it does not route from login component and if path="./Signup" then it does not load at the start up. code is listed below .any help will be appreciated.

```
<Route exact path='/Signup' component={Signup} />
<Route exact path='/' component={Signup} />
```

Comment: can you please share how you are redirecting to signup from login component?

Comment: there is a button in logi component when pressed it calls an onclick function which uses history.push to move to signup